# jinja template for loop

Tags: google-app-engine, jinja2, google-cloud-datastore

I would like to break the for loop in jinja template/ I want to run it only once how should I do that.

```
{% for one in ones %}
  {{ one.column1 }}
{% endfor %}
```

I am getting 'ones' from the python code in different file and processing in jinja template. I want to print {{one.column1}} only once. column1 is one of the fields in the google app engine datastore entity. the value of column1 is same for all the iteration of the for-loop.  Is there any other way to do this without for loop?

Comment: Have you tried: `{{ones[0].column1}}`? (Without the `for` loop.)

Answer (score 2):

If you really want break/continue support in jinja2 -- take a look on [Loop Controls](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/extensions/#loop-controls) extension.

Just add it into "extensions" jinja's environment arguments:

```
'environment_args': {
  'autoescape': True,
  'extensions': [
    'jinja2.ext.loopcontrols',
  ],
  'auto_reload': False,
}
```